# Como extraer dato dentro de un cadena

Tags: php

Necesito extraer el `ID` de los productos de `Amazon`. Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación para calcular el costo de compra y envío de productos de tiendas online. Había logrado traer la información con `cURL` y `XPath`. Con `Amazon` no me sirvió, así que buscando encontré una librería para usar `ItemLookUp` (API AMAZON) con el `ID` del producto. Como la forma que va funcionar la aplicación es pegando el enlace del producto, necesito alguna forma de extraer esa información del enlace (ID).

Ejemplo:

```
https://www.amazon.com/TotalMount-PlayStation-Slim-Mounts-wall-near/dp/B07281WC5W/ref=sr_1_2?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1497043401&sr=1-2-spons&keywords=playstation&psc=1
```

El dato que necesito extraer es lo que está dentro de `/dp/IDPRODUCTO/ ->B07281WC5W`. ¿Hay alguna función en `PHP` que me permita extraer ese dato? Ya con ese dato completaría mi última pieza de rompecabezas.

---

Me funcionan las opciones que me han dado pero me he dado cuenta que los link de amazon tiene como 3 variaciones, así que tendré que hacer mis cambios, cuando lo haya adaptado a la aplicación les digo como quedo al final.

Gracias.

---

Bueno ya me funcionó y lo adapte a lo que estaba desarrollando, lo de variaciones era que vi unos productos que no tenían el mismo formato en el enlace y entonces no retornaba ningún dato.

```
require_once( "AmazonAPI.php");

$enlace = ($_POST["cotizar"]);

$amazonAPI = new AmazonAPI('YOUR API KEY', 'YOUR SECRET KEY', 'YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG' );

$amazonAPI->SetRetrieveAsArray();
$listado = explode("/", $enlace);
$sku = $listado[5];

$items = $amazonAPI->ItemLookUp( $sku );

foreach ($items as $item) {

            return $item ;

}
```

Mas o menos así. En móvil tiene un / mas así que le puse una condicional para detectar móviles y $sku = $listado[6];

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son esas 3 variaciones? Sin una definición clara de cómo es la URL y qué parte te interesa obtener, esta pregunta no es clara. Además, ¿qué intentaste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [explode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de `PHP`:

```
<?php

/**
 * URL de Amazon
 */
$url = "http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07281WC5W";

/**
 *  Tenemos 5 (slash) antes del identificador del producto
 */
$listado = explode("/", $url);

/**
 * Por lo tanto nuestro identificador será el elemento número 5
 */
print $listado[5] . "\n";

?>
```

Resultado:

> B07281WC5W

**¿Cómo funciona?**

La función [explode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de `php` *corta* una cadena de acuerdo a un elemento como **delimitador**.

Como lo [explica](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-description) `PHP`:

> Devuelve un array de string, siendo cada uno un substring del parámetro string formado por la división realizada por los delimitadores indicados en el parámetro delimiter.

En ese caso, empezamos por **definir** nuestro delimitador (en este caso será el `/`) y contamos la cantidad de **delimitadores** que existen hasta donde está el dato que queremos obtener (identificador):

> https: **//** www.amazon.com **/** TotalMount-PlayStation-Slim-Mounts-wall-near **/** dp **/** B07281WC5W/ref=sr_1_2?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1497043401&sr=1-2-spons&keywords=playstation&psc=1

Lo que nos **indicará** que el identificador del producto, se encontrará en la quinta **posición** del arreglo devuelto por explode().

Answer (score 1):

Si la `URL` siempre tendrá esa estructura (el `ID` se encuentra después de `/dp/`) puedes usar una expresión regular para extraerla:

```
$url = 'https://www.amazon.com/TotalMount-PlayStation-Slim-Mounts-wall-near/dp/B07281WC5W/ref=sr_1_2?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1497043401&sr=1-2-spons&keywords=playstation&psc=1';
$id = preg_replace('/^.*?\/dp\/([^\/]+).*$/', '$1', $url);
echo $id;
```

[Aquí te dejo](http://ideone.com/xbEQPR) un ejemplo funcional en Ideone.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que necesitas, esta función que armé puede ayudarte. La probé y funcionó para la `URL` que indicas. Pruébala tú y espero que te funcione:

```
function getCode ($url) {
    $copiar = false;
    foreach (explode ("/", $url) as $codigo) {
        if ($copiar) {
            return $codigo;
            break;
        }
        if ($codigo == "dp") {
            $copiar = true;
        }
    }
    return "no encontrado";
}
echo getCode("https:// www.amazon.com/dp/B07281WC5W/?tag=stackoverfl08-20");
```

La función utilizada es `explode`, pero para tu caso de `URL` dinámicas solo encontré un patron: `/dp/`. Luego de `dp` viene el código que necesitas. La función solo recorre el arreglo que forma `explode` y luego de encontrar `dp` retorna el siguiente item del arreglo.